# assignment and function execution

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure to understand why this is resulting to undefined

```
  var foo = {
    bar: function(){ return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  }
  console.log(typeof (f = foo.bar)());
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You need to invoke the `bar` function to get the `baz`</strike>

```
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        return this.baz;
    },
    baz: 1
};
console.log(typeof (f = foo.bar()));
```

This depends on **how the function is called**. When calling `f()` the context is set to the `Window` object. As there is no global variable `baz` the function `f` will return `undefined`.

You can verify this by logging the `this` inside the `bar()`.

```js
var foo = {
  bar: function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this.baz;
  },
  baz: 1
}

console.log('Called on foo', typeof foo.bar());
console.log('Called as `f()`', typeof(f = foo.bar)());
```

To change the context of the function, you can use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```js
var foo = {
    bar: function () {
        return this.baz;
    },
    baz: 1
};

console.log('Called as `f().call(foo)`', typeof (f = foo.bar).call(foo));
console.log('Called as `f().apply(foo)`', typeof (f = foo.bar).apply(foo));
console.log('Using bind', typeof (f = foo.bar).bind(foo)());
```

Comment: but how to explain the undefined result ? what is the order of execution of the sequence this what I don't really get, this more a theoretical question.

Comment: got it , seems obvious now, not a problem of assignment order but a simple scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

What were you expecting to find?

If you were expecting to get "function" as in foo.bar then you should rewrite your code like this:

```
 var foo = {
    bar: function(){ return this.baz; },
    baz: 1
  }
  console.log(typeof (f = foo.bar));
```

I think you have a set of parentheses which shouldn't exists -> right after the "(f = foo.bar)" part.

But if you were trying to get the type of foo.baz then you should rewrite you code like this:

```
 var foo = {
    bar: function(){ return foo.baz; },
    baz: 1
  }
  console.log(typeof (f = foo.bar));
```

"this" is undefined because it is a singletone js object, not a class (function).